# How to test PDF downloads with selenium & capybara in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, selenium, capybara

I am attempting to test a PDF file as part of my Rails test suite. I have a page which has a PDF download button identified by `a#download_pdf`. What I want to do is grab the file that is generated and compare it to a stored master file. I cannot figure out how to grab this file though. Once I click the button I get the popup asking if I want to save or open the file. What do I do?! How can I get that darn file to save.

```
@page.find('a#download_pdf').click
```

This is my **selenium_helper.rb**

```
require_relative 'test_helper'
require 'database_cleaner'

ENV["RAILS_ENV"] = "test"

# Because of the use of mixins, the order of loading matters
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/integration/page_objects/page_object.rb'

Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/integration/page_objects/mixins/*.rb'].each do |page_object|
  require page_object
end

Dir[File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/integration/page_objects/*/*.rb'].each do |page_object|
  require page_object
end

module MyApp
  class SeleniumIntegrationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    include Capybara::DSL
    include Warden::Test::Helpers
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
    fixtures :all
    self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

    setup do
      DatabaseCleaner.start

      # Stub out Recurly methods
      Recurly::Account.stubs(:find)

      # We need to make the size of the browser bigger.  Otherwise Capybara
      # can't find elements when a form goes below the bottom of the browser.
      page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1200,800)
    end

    ...
  end   
end
```